# i have a problem with media player (android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

iam doing an education app for kids

i have a activity with all the alphabet and when you press any alphabet it make the sound of it
using media player

the problem is after a number of touches on the alphabet , it depends on the device , non of the alphabet make sound and all the buttons stop making sound

at the begining i had one variable , and i would re assign it each time

i tired declaring 28 variable , one for each letter and it didnt work

please help :( please

Comment: We can't help you fix code that you haven't shared with us.  Please [edit] your question to include the code that you're having trouble with (**not** the whole program, just enough to demonstrate the problem), a [mcve] would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem but now my problem is solved you need to do something like that

write this code outside your button `OnClickListener`.

```
MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(your_Activty.this , R.raw.your_sound);
```

then in your `OnClickListener` just write this

```
mediaplayer.start () ;
```

I hope this work for you.